# Could someone explain to me why my code works? (Asyncio python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm using python 3.9, so I've got my code to work, but I don't understand how the error came to be in the first place, I looked at the docs, and other answers but I didn't really understand them.

```
import asyncio
from selenium import webdriver

async def ToSite():
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    await driver.get(url)

async def main(func):
    await func()

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.call_soon(ToSite())
asyncio.run(asyncio.sleep(0.5))

print("hi there how are you")
```

This results in the following traceback and output:

```
hi there how are you
C:\Users\yapji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:667: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ToSite' was never awaited
```

I tried to `await` it by passing the in the main function that I made like this:
`loop.call_soon(main(ToSite))` This will result in the same error, as above, the only difference being instead of saying 'ToSite' was never awaited, it is replaced by 'main' was never awaited. Then I modified the `main` function with the `return` keyword like this:

```
async def main(func):
   return await func()
```

Then I passed that into `loop.call_soon()` again like i did in the first attempt to fix it, which will give the same error.

Then I tried this which fixed it:

```
import asyncio
from selenium import webdriver

async def ToSite():
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)

async def main(func):
    return await func()

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.call_soon(asyncio.run(ToSite()))
print("hi there how are you")
```

And I have no idea why this works. I just know it does. I checked the type of `asyncio.run(ToSite())` and it's a `None` type. So I'm not sure what's happening. I also check the type of `ToSite` and `ToSite()` the results being function at , and it is a coroutine, respectively. So I'm not sure what's going on. So could someone explain, why the error occurred and what happened when I fixed it?

Comment: In addition to what Grismar explained, note that if you're using `asyncio.run()` (which is a good idea), you should never call `new_event_loop()` or `loop.call_soon()` outside of the event loop. This is because `asyncio.run()` will create a fresh event loop and run in that. With `asyncio.run()` you should put your program in an async function (conventionally called `main`) and run or schedule everything off of that.

Comment: Alright. What if instead of using `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()` what if I use `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` instead? Then call `asycnio.run()` like [this](http://www.hastebin.net/xuwacenyby.py) So this wouldn't create a new event loop. It'd just get the existing one.

Comment: Or would [this](http://www.hastebin.net/ijudukajah.py) be a more proper way. Since I'm going to use `call_soon()` I might as well place it at the top, so it can be executed as soon as possible.

Comment: You can use `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` (and call `call_soon`) *inside* your async defs. Also note that you don't need the stub `main()` which just instantiates and awaits the coroutine you've given it, you can `asyncio.run(ToSite())` as well. Finally, the code you've given doesn't appear to be async because the coroutine doesn't await anything. Perhaps you need to switch to an async API for selenium.

Comment: Yeah I tried using the `main()` function, to fit the general way of running things. I tried to await `driver.get(url)` but that doesn't work. [This](http://www.hastebin.net/rihurutuze.py) is the code. And the traceback is found [here](http://www.hastebin.net/obakewagob.tex).
But I did get [this](http://www.hastebin.net/ihibypeqyb.py) to work. Where I did `await` the `ToSite()` function. Which is I think the way the code is usually ran, conventionally anyways.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't just apply await to a non-async function, you need to switch to a library that is designed for asyncio, perhaps [this one](https://pypi.org/project/aioselenium/). The final version of your code may work, but it's not async, so you can just as well remove the asyncio parts because they're not doing anything.

Comment: Is it possible for me for me to get your contact? Such as your discord, or a way we can communicate? If You don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurred initially because you passed `ToSite()` to `loop.call_soon()`. `ToSite` is named poorly, because it looks like a class, but is just a function, so `ToSite()` calls that function and whatever it returns is passed to `loop.call_soon()` as a callback. It returns an awaitable, as it was defined as an `async` function, but nowhere is `ToSite()` awaited.

You then proceeded to `loop.call_soon(main(ToSite))`. This changes things, because now `main` is called with the `ToSite` function as its `func` parameter, which is called and then awaited at the end of `main` by `return await func()`. Here, `func()` returns an awaitable, `await` awaits it and the result is returned.

However, `main` itself is `async` and will thus return an awaitable, which is never awaited - which explains the second error.

In the final example, you cut out `main` again (it serves no purpose) and instead call `loop.call_soon(asyncio.run(ToSite()))`. The awaitable returned by `ToSite()` is now passed to `asyncio.run()` - it proceeds to create and event loop and create it (as per its documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run)

Comment: ToSite() calls that function. 
I thought that since `ToSite()` is prefixed with `async def` it becomes a coroutine function, and when ran, returns a couroutine object instead of executing it.

Comment: It does, but the awaitable that's returned (the coroutine object) is never awaited anywhere, you just pass it to `call_soon()` - I mentioned the naming because I thought you may have confused yourself and thought it somehow was a class. Clearly not, but that explains why you get the error. `call_soon()` doesn't await it.